# Pi wireless access point requires service networking restart before devices can connect

Tags: wireless, pi-4, access-point

Firstly, I am completely new to Raspberry Pi and Linux so I apologize that I may need spoon-feeding.
I've installed Raspian Buster on my SD card and got the Raspberry Pi 4 booted up. My plan was to setup up the Pi as a wireless access point and provide internet to connected devices via a Huawei E3372 4G dongle.

I followed the tutorial here:
[Using the Raspberry Pi as an access point to share an internet connection (bridge)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) starting just over half way down the webpage. I replaced eth0 with eth1 anywhere it occurred since my 4G dongle shows up on eth1 and that was to be used for the Pi's internet connection.

This alone did not work. I also needed the code from here:
[Setup a raspberry pi wireless access point](https://www.thegeekpub.com/240065/setup-a-raspberry-pi-wireless-access-point/) specifically to edit the interfaces file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add the code:

```
# AP Bridge setup
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth1 wlan0
```

After this, I connected the 4G dongle to the Pi and was able to get it working as planned. However, in order for the 4G internet connection to start working and for devices to connect to the Pi access point, I need to run the command:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

After running that everything works fine. But I need the Pi to work without me having to manually run this command.
Maybe somebody can help me identify the problem requiring the networking service restart, or alternatively, show me how to automate this command after the Pi boots up?

EDIT:
It has also occurred to me that perhaps the networking service isn't started automatically? How could I check that and how could I make sure it gets started at boot?

Comment: I haven't looked at any of the links you mentioned. You have picked some random links - at least one uses a network manager unsupported by the Raspbian OS, others seem to be using obsolete Debian networking. Make life easier for yourself by following an official Foundation guide. Setting up an Access Point is not a beginners task.

Comment: You might get some help from the other 2 or 3 people who use it. NetworkManager is incompatible with Debian networking.

Comment: I've started from scratch and didn't use network manager this time. Much simpler explanation of steps followed now but still have same problem at the end.

Comment: You can try an alternative setup without fiddling with deprecated Debian networking and additional helpers: [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866).